# Semantic UI - Following menu example

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I'm new to Semantic UI and I want to implement following menu as seen in [Semantic UI's documentation](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/menu.html) on right side. I want to implement this functionallity to fixed top menu - so when id of header element is reached, active element in menu should be changed. I was looking at code of docs.js where this is implemented for documentation's site, but this code is pretty complex if you are using Semantic UI for the first time. I have those classes for my menu: ui large top fixed hidden menu

Is there already built-in following menu (probably not since it's not mentioned in docs?) or I add it with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

semantic-ui only gives you the styling.  Once you click on a menu item, it is up to you to update the item's active status.

This is how we have it implemented in our code -

```
const menuNav = $('.ui.menu.menu-component .item');
menuNav.on('click', function (item) {
  menuNav.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

The other thing to remember is that you need to check the URL on page load so that you can set the appropriate item label to active.